# How to show the City (Location) of Events in Event Lists using Drupal Views

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views, location

We need to show a list of upcoming events on our website. For this I have installed and integrated the Drupal Views module. The Events List in Views works like a charm except for one thing.
We would also like to display the city of the Location where each Events is being held in the list. Unfortunately I can not find this field when clicking the Add field button in the Views create Display page.
How to go about? Am I missing something?

Many thanks for your kind attention.

Comment: Thank you very much for this pointer. It helped me to show the city of the event location on the events listing. Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The location of an event is stored as a CiviCRM Address field, not as a field on the event. As such, it won't show up if you are filtering fields for CiviCRM Event in the Add fields dialog. Remove the filter, or filter on CiviCRM Address instead, and relevant fields should show up. Here is a screenshot for adding a field in CiviCRM 4.7 on Drupal 7 on one of our sites:

[image: Screenshot of add fields dialog for CiviCRM Address fields]

Similarly, any custom event fields you have will appear under the field grouping under CiviCRM Custom.

Note that not every address field is populated when you add an event address, but the city should certainly be one of them.